# Do I have 'health'?

Tags: portal-series

In Portal (and Portal 2), I can get hurt by lasers, bullets, etc. Do I have a finite amount of health that is depleted every time I get singed, or is it a case of sustaining damage for a continuous amount of time resulting in death?

Comment: I think its continuous damage = death

Comment: @fireDude67 I *think* that's what it is too, but I have no evidence.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You do have 100 health, only the exact number isn't shown on the HUD.

Continuous damage will kill you, but your health fully regenerates *very* quickly when you aren't damaged for a bit.

You can observe this in Portal 1 by giving yourself the HEV suit (console command `give item_suit`, needs `sv_cheats` to be enabled), which causes your health to be visible.

[image]

In Portal 2, issuing `ent_dump player` after being shot at by a turret displayed the following, so it's pretty safe to assume that it works the exact same way as in 1:

```
] ent_dump player
  [...]
  max_health: 100
  health: 10
  [...]
```

Comment: You can't even kill yourself with lasers.

Comment: @GnomeSlice I'm pretty sure Portal 2's lasers do kill you at some point, if you mash your face into them repeatedly. Maybe it's just the co-op bots, though.

Comment: I've definitely done it for minutes at a time with no exciting results.

Comment: I've killed myself with lasers.

Comment: @GnomeSlice Maybe this was changed in a patch and you tried it before that. Using `ent_dump`, I've verified that lasers do between 2 and 3 damage.

Comment: I've only played it on the PS3.

Comment: I too have killed myself with lasers, on the ps3.